# Dropdown de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, navbar, dropdown

tengo un problema con el código del navbar en Bootstrap.

El problema es que el Dropwdown no funciona. Cuando le doy clic para que se extienda no se hace. Además, cuando cambio a vista de móvil, el botón en donde se contraen las opciones se muestra al hacer clic, pero para cerrarlo, le doy clic de nuevo y no se cierra. No sé si sea algún problema de versión o algo así, estuve investigando y no logré solucionarlo. Si me ayudan sería genial

No sé qué pueda ser; les dejo el código.

Gracias de antemano.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Paseo del Viento</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="navegador">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Paseo del viento</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ingresas 2 veces la librería

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate lo que señala la documentación sobre el [bundle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle)

**Traducción automática:**

> **Bundle**
> Incluye cada plugin y dependencia de JavaScript de Bootstrap
> con uno de nuestros dos paquetes. Ambos e incluyen Popper para
> nuestros tooltips y popovers

Es decir, o colocas `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` o colocas (`popper.min.js` + `bootstrap.min.js`), pero no ambas

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Paseo del Viento</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navegador">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Paseo del viento</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                               aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! Sí funcionó